# AWS Ruby SDK v2, Cloudfront list_distributions, iterate over the results

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the new ruby sdk (v2) for aws cloud front

I'm trying to list all of my distributions, using the `list_distributions` method

the response that is get is a PageableResponse,

when i try to iterate over the results it seems that i get only one page,

```
page = cloudfront.list_distributions
page.each do |page|
  # only one page ....
end
```

but in the "distribution_list" hash, the "next_marker" attribute, contains the value for the request, and the "is_truncated" attribute is set to true,

if i will call `list_distributions` method again with the next_marker, i will get the next set of results...

why is that ?

it seems strange that i have to ways to iterate over the response ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have describe exact behavior like it is documented in the official SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/ListDistributions.html. I think this is quite common pattern used to reduce load on the backend server as in many cases only part of the list is needed.

Comment: Agree, But the weird thing though, is that in the ruby sdk, the response to the list distributions request is a `PageableResponse`, which suppose to do the iterative requests for you (if i have understood it correctly) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a [reply](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=588070&#588070) from a thread in the AWS discussions forum that said it's a bug in the SDK and it should be resolved in the next release.

[Link to the issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/issues/169)

Comment: The fix has been released.